# How can I find the meanings of certain words of the Inuit language?

Tags: translation, inuit

I have been reading the [Inuit and Chukchee mythology on Sacred Texts](http://www.sacred-texts.com/nam/inu/index.htm).

There are many words here that appear to be transliteration rather than translations. Is there an Inuit/Chukchee language dictionary? Or even research available for me to consult to get a better idea of what they mean according to the English language during the late 19/20 century ideas? (Or even today?)

I have copied and pasted these words into a search and all I get is the text I am currently reading or nothing, but not a translation of what it may mean in English.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You have this dictionary: https://library.alaska.gov/hist/hist_docs/docs/anlm/200078.pdf

I would like to notice the problem when reading such old books made by pioneers is that the lack of any norms makes it difficult to follow them. The way they were writing names, and the fact that due to the time they were writing a creature could be named X by tribe 1, and Z by tribe 2.
Hence it is good to have a dictionary of that time. The one building those faced those exact problems.